# inheriting ttk instead of Tk

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, tkinter, multiple-inheritance

I am building an application where I set up a class 'App' and pass the root when creating an App object.

```
Class App(root):
    .....
    .....

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
```

Then I seen examples where instead of the above setup, the class was inheriting Tk.

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(tki.Tk):
    """Project Engineer Release Help Tool"""
    def __init__(self):
        tki.Tk.__init__(self)
```

I thought this was much cleaner so I implemented the cleaner version. It all works fine but I have been using ttk.Style() and wanted to inherit ttk. I can't seem to get this to work though. Any help welcome.

Edit for clarity (and typo in the first example):

I was doing the following. Note: using `ttk.Entry`.

```
from tkinter import ttk

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root 
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self.root, width=40)
        self.entry.grid(sticky='n', padx=6, pady=12, columnspan=2)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.return_click)
        self.entry.focus() 

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
.......
.......
```

I changed to inheriting Tk and the style/theme of all my widgets have changed. I would like to stick with inheriting from tkinter but I want to use the ttk themed widgets. How would this be achieved ?

Comment: Thank you @marcusshep for the edit. I write quickly and my illiteracy shows :). Thank god for numbers

Comment: `Class` -> `class`. `App` should inherit `Tk`, which is a class, rather than `root`, which is an object. You should then initialize `root = App()` instead of `root = Tk()` in `main`.

Comment: You don't need to override `__init__` if you don't change any of the args.

Comment: Yep I agree with you in main when i inherit from Tk i use app = App()
 app.mainloop(). ttk is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html

Comment: i will try with out __init__ now.

Comment: ttk being a module and not a class is probably an issue here. But then taught I would be able to do the following for Style().                    ttk.Style.__init__(self)  but no :(

Comment: If you get an error, post it. And please post the actual code you are running. The stuff you posted has at least one typo I already pointed out.

Comment: Not sure if throwing up the whole thing will help. Added bit for clarity and to correct the example you rightly pointed out.

Comment: Please please please proof read your work.

Comment: I will be more careful honestly its not lazyness, cheers @Mad Physicist p.s. love the name

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what to make of yours :)

Comment: Golf fish memory :) .... 10 second tom :) just realised that could really be misunderstood lol